# nginx hooks ? or any other approach

Tags: nginx

I have couple files on my web project. They are all sending to client with nginx help.

But i want to know (and to show for end users) how many times file was downloaded.

For example  file has url like: example.com/file.ppt

and nginx settings is next:

```
location ~* \.(ppt|swf)$ {
    root /path/to/static/content;
    expires     30d;
}
```

so my question: can nginx sent some request by some url ? or something else, when someone tries to download certain file ?

Answer (score 0):

You could count successed file downloads in nginx access.log for example with grep:

grep -c file.ppt access.log

Comment: there are a lot of logs (and .gz too) and how i can determine that something already counted and something not ?

Comment: you could uncompress them one by one and count manually. For future counting you could use nginx's logrotate script, like this:
`
    postrotate
        [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
        /usr/bin/logparser.sh
`
Just make sure to add parameter "delaycompress" to logrotate config